# Position a dynamic QDialog with respect to display/screen size in Qt

Tags: qt, dialog, position, screen

I'd like to position and then show a dialog with respect to the display. The dialog has a label. The dialog expands based on the size of the label.

Below is my code that does not work. It tries to show the dialog at the center of the screen (the dialog is shown at the center by default and this code is just for evaluation):

```
QDialog splash;
QVBoxLayout *laySplash = new QVBoxLayout(&splash);
QLabel *lblText = new QLabel;
laySplash->addWidget(lblText);
lblText->setText("hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! ");

int intScreenHeight = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry().height();
int intScreenWidth = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry().width();

splash.layout()->update();
splash.layout()->activate();

int intSplashLeft = (intScreenWidth / 2) - (splash.width() / 2);
int intSplashTop = (intScreenHeight /2) - (splash.height() / 2);
splash.move(intSplashLeft, intSplashTop);

splash.exec();
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I am using Qt5 in Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that the layout will only update the size of the widget after it is visible, a possible solution is to force it by calling the method `adjustSize()` of the `QDialog`.

There are several ways to center a widget:

1. First form:

---

```
QDialog splash;
QVBoxLayout *laySplash = new QVBoxLayout(&splash);
QLabel *lblText = new QLabel;
laySplash->addWidget(lblText);
lblText->setText("hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! ");
splash.adjustSize();

splash.setGeometry(
    QStyle::alignedRect(
        Qt::LeftToRight,
        Qt::AlignCenter,
        splash.size(),
        qApp->desktop()->availableGeometry()
    )
);

splash.exec();
```

2. Second Form:

---

```
QDialog splash;
QVBoxLayout *laySplash = new QVBoxLayout(&splash);
QLabel *lblText = new QLabel;
laySplash->addWidget(lblText);
lblText->setText("hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! ");
splash.adjustSize();
QPoint p = QApplication::desktop()->geometry().center()-splash.rect().center();
splash.move(p);

splash.exec();
```

3. Third form(your method):

---

```
QDialog splash;
QVBoxLayout *laySplash = new QVBoxLayout(&splash);
QLabel *lblText = new QLabel;
laySplash->addWidget(lblText);
lblText->setText("hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! ");

splash.adjustSize();
int intScreenHeight = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry().height();
int intScreenWidth = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry().width();

int intSplashLeft = (intScreenWidth / 2) - (splash.width() / 2);
int intSplashTop = (intScreenHeight /2) - (splash.height() / 2);
splash.move(intSplashLeft, intSplashTop);

splash.exec();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try my code, it works
Create a function called set geometry, and pass your QDialog pointer and the percentage of size with respect to screen. Say if you want your dialog to be of size 50% of the total screen then pass 50

```
void setGeometry(QDialog *dialogBox, int PercentageOfScreen)
{
    int x, y, w, h;
    QRect rect = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
    int screen_width = rect.width();
    int screen_height = rect.height();

    //Represent Percentage in decimals
    float PercentageOfScreenFloat = (float)PercentageOfScreen/100;

    //Calculate w and h
    w = (PercentageOfScreenFloat * screen_width);
    h = (PercentageOfScreenFloat * screen_height);

    //Check for max and min size hints
    int minW = dialogBox->minimumWidth();
    int minH = dialogBox->minimumHeight();

    int maxW = dialogBox->maximumWidth();
    int maxH = dialogBox->maximumHeight();

    if(w<minW || h<minH)
    {
        w = minW;
        h = minH;
    }
    else if(w>maxW || h>maxH)
    {
        w = maxW;
        h = maxH;
    }

    //Now Calculate x and y
    x = screen_width / 2;
    x = x - w / 2;

    y = screen_height / 2;
    y = y - h / 2;

    dialogBox->setGeometry(x, y, w, h);

}
```

Comment: `PercentageOfScreenFloat` was declared as `float` .. but when you Calculate w and h, in the calculations you are casting it again to `float` .. whats the reason?

Comment: @MohammadKanan Thanks for pointing it out, it wasn't necessary. Now i edited the code